# Subtracting blur value from box-shadow property through SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have been cogitating on this for a while now. In my SCSS I have the following:

```
$shadow: 0 0 25px rgb(46, 46, 46);

div {
   box-shadow: $shadow;  
}
```

How can I subtract the 25px of blur by, let's say 10 so that I may use a blur of 15 pixels? Furthermore, how do I select the blur value? Considering I want to apply a box-shadow on a div element:

```
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. You've got everything you want, why don't you write `0 0 15px rgb( 46, 46, 46 );` as value of the variable? You could also nest variables if you want to substract the 10 dynamically from the `$shadow` variable.

Comment: Nested variables are the way to go here. You can't subtract 10 from it after it's initialized

Comment: But I want to subtract 10 from the blue value. How could I specify that using a nested variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$shadow` variable is simply a list of values.  If the blur is always going to be the 3rd item in the list (such as in your example), then what you're looking at is something like this:

```
div {
   box-shadow: nth($shadow, 1) nth($shadow, 2) nth($shadow, 3) - 15px nth($shadow, 4);
}
```

If the blur is in another *valid* position in the list (maybe it's an inset shadow), then you'll need to start doing things like checking the length of the list and/or examine the first element to see if it is `inset`:

```
div {
    @if nth($shadow, 1) == inset {
        box-shadow: nth($shadow, 1) nth($shadow, 2) nth($shadow, 3) nth($shadow, 4) - 15px nth($shadow, 5);
    } @else {
        box-shadow: nth($shadow, 1) nth($shadow, 2) nth($shadow, 3) - 15px nth($shadow, 4);
    }
}
```

Alternately, you could do it programatically:

```
$shadow: 0 0 25px rgb(46, 46, 46);

@function adjust-shadow($shadow, $position, $adjustment) {
    $x: ();
    $shift: if(nth($shadow, 1) == inset, -1, 0);

    @for $i from 1 through length($shadow) {
        $p: $i + $shift;
        @if $position == color and $i == length($shadow) {
            $x: append($x, $adjustment);
        } @else if ($position == x-offset and $p == 1) or ($position == y-offset and $p == 2) or ($position == blur and $p == 3) {
            $x: append($x, nth($shadow, $i) + $adjustment);
        } @else {
            $x: append($x, nth($shadow, $i));
        }
    }
    @return $x;
}

.foo {
    box-shadow: adjust-shadow($shadow, blur, -15px);
}

.bar {
    box-shadow: adjust-shadow($shadow, color, blue);
}

.baz {
    box-shadow: adjust-shadow(adjust-shadow($shadow, blur, -15px), y-offset, -2), adjust-shadow($shadow, blur, 10px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a new variable for the blur value:

```
$blur: 25px - 10;
$shadow: 0 0 $blur rgb(46, 46, 46);

div {
   box-shadow: $shadow;  
}
```

Depending on your overall needs, you might be better served by writing a mixin.